# Custom JSTL TagLib and TomCat Problem

Tags: tomcat, jstl, noclassdeffounderror

I've just created a custom taglib which runs fine with Jetty. When using TomCat 6.0 I get the following exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I'm using Facelets and JSF 1.2.

Thxs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the following to my pom.xml

javax.servlet
    jstl
    1.2

That fixed the problem. Not sure why it worked on Jetty but not Tomcat.

Comment: Apparently because JSTL is already included in Jetty. Tomcat indeed doesn't ship with JSTL.